# How to determine the date one day prior to a given date in Scala?

Tags: scala

How to implement the following Java segment in Scala? That is, how to determine the date one day prior to a given date in Scala?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(myDate);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,-1);
Date oneDayBefore= cal.getTime();
```

Thank you.

Comment: Replace `Calendar cal` with `var cal` and `Date oneDayBefore` with `var oneDayBefore` and you'll get a valid scala code.

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.util.Calendar
val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
//cal.setTime(myDate); 
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,-1);
val oneDayBefore = cal.getTime();
>>oneDayBefore: java.util.Date = Sun Dec 29 11:52:17 MSK 2013
```

Answer (score 3):

First you must know that any Java API can be imported and used in Scala, so the translation is trivial. Second, for date/time manipulation in both Java and Scala (but especially in Scala) I suggest you adopt the [Joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

Comment: In Scala you can use https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time to make Joda-Time even nicer to use.

Answer (score 2):

For a more Scala-esque feel you can use [nscala-time](https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time) which is a wrapper around [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), the de-facto non-JDK Date utility:

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports.DateTime._

  //if myDate is DateTime
  val myJodaDate = yesterday
  println( myJodaDate - 1.day )
  //2013-12-28T12:35:22.248Z

  //if myDate is DateTime and only interested in the date(no-time) portion
  println( (myJodaDate - 1.day).toLocalDate )
  //2013-12-28

  //if myDate is java.util.Date and interested in returning java.util.Date too
  val myJavaDate = myJodaDate.toDate
  println( (new DateTime(myJavaDate) - 1.day).toDate )
  //Sat Dec 28 12:39:12 GMT 2013
```